Как задать зумирование карту относительно выбранной точки/центра карты?
Зум карты всегда происходит относительно позиции курсора на карте, а хотелось бы, чтобы зум всегда был относительно центра / выбранной точки, вне зависимости от положения курсора (как в Яндекс Маркете при активном табе  Курьером, например)
Есть ощущение, что для текущего релиза такое поведение не предусмотрено :(
В ранних версиях можно было задавать параметры centering и position для setZoom

В API 3.0 выбор точки зуммирования (курсор или центр карты) определяет ZoomStrategy.
Вам нужен "zoomToCenter".

А если мы говорим про версию API 2.1.79? Есть ли функционал там?
